# Regex remove everything thats outside { }

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex to remove everything outside the { }
for example:

before:
`|loader|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|{"data" : "some data" }`

after: 
`{"data" : "some data" }`

with @Marcelo's  regex this works but not if there are others {} inside the {} like here:

```
"|loader|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
   {'data':  
       [ 
         {'data':'some data'}
       ],  
   }"
```

Comment: The flip-side of, "remove everything but X," is, "keep X". So you could just match `/{.*?}/`.

Comment: how many `{}` are gonna be there? would they be nested?

Comment: thanks all.now im using
('|loader|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|{"data" : "some data" ').match(/{.*?}/,'')
in js. thanks

Comment: Would the string inside `{}` contain the `}` character? something like `{"regex":"^\d{3}$"}`? If not, go with @Marcelo's regex. Otherwise, it's complicated.

Comment: inside the {} its json and could contain any other { , thats a problem

Comment: on second thought that shouldn't be a problem as long as your regex is greedy. glycerine's version is greedy and should work fine. @marcelo version is non greedy and would stop searching at the first `}`. Btw, both have forgotten to escape { and }. It should be `/\{.*\}/`

Comment: @wemakeweb: why aren't you using a JSON parsing library?

Comment: I did not forget to escape the `{` and `}`. The OP didn't specify a language or library, so I assumed Perl, which doesn't require it.

Comment: @marcelo I didn't think from that angle - I don't know Perl to begin with :)

Comment: I always escape the braces anyway.  It communicates my intentions more clearly and it gives me one less flavor-specific quirk to keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work - What language are you using - Obviously Regex... but what server side - then I can put it into a statement for you

```
{(.*)}
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape the `{` and `}`?

Comment: Sure, but it depends on which language its used in to attain how the complete regex will look this is devoid of flags n'all `\{(.*)\}`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do:

```
Regex.Replace("|loader|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|{\"data\" : \"some data\" }", ".*?({.*?}).*?", "$1");
```

(C# syntax, regex should be fine in most languages afaik)

Comment: Why would you use replace to pull out a match in a String?

Comment: Works with multiple instances and automatically concatenates them? Or maybe just because I don't like C#'s Match operator (It returns an object that does stuff instead of a string). It's kind of irrelevant, this is a tiny example and this way will work just fine.

Comment: Don't you need to escape the `{` and `}`?

Comment: @polygenelubricants Nope, not in C# (might have to in other languages).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in Java:

```
    String[] tests = {
        "{ in in in } out",                 // "{ in in in }"
        "out { in in in }",                 // "{ in in in }"
        "   { in }   ",                     // "{ in }"
        "pre { in1 } between { in2 } post", // "{ in1 }{ in2 }"
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\})[^{]+", ""));
    }
```

The regex is:

```
(?<=^|\})[^{]+
```

Basically we match any string that is "outside", as defined as something that follows a literal `}`, or starting from the beginning of the string `^`, until it reaches a literal`{`, i.e. we match `[^{]+`, We replace these matched "outside" string with an empty string.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

  - `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind

---

#### A non-regex Javascript solution, for nestable but single top-level `{...}`

Depending on the problem specification (it isn't exactly clear), you can also do something like this:

```
var s = "pre { { { } } } post";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("{"), s.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);
```

This does exactly what it says: given an arbitrary string `s`, it takes its substring starting from the first `{` to the last `}` (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can try

```
s = '|loader|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|{"data" : "some data" }';
s = s.replace(/[^{]*({[^}]*})/g,'$1');
alert(s);
```

of course this will not work if "some data" has curly braces so the solution highly depends on your input data.

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner

Comment: i use string.match(/\{.*\}/,'') and it works also for curly braces inside the first

Answer (score 0):

For those who searching this for PHP, only this one worked for me:

```
preg_replace("/.*({.*}).*/","$1",$input);
```